# How to pause keyframe animation when not hovered

Tags: css, performance, css-animations, keyframe

I have a keyframe animation to move a mask position and is applied when the button is hovered. But when I stop hovering it, **the mask position reset to 0** which make the transition a bit odd.

---

The following is the keyframes:

```css
@keyframes waving-mask {
  0% {
    mask-position: 0% 0;
  }
  100% {
    mask-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

---

How do I run the animation when hovered and pause right at the keyframe position when I stop hovering the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, the hover `animation` was a wrong approach. Instead put the animation in the class and then add

```css
animation-play-state: paused;
```

Then add the following to the hover pseudo class

```css
animation-play-state: running;
```

More about [animation-play-state](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_animation-play-state&preval=paused)